# How to interpret "much to" in "much to the chagrin of its original investors" sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In "much to the chagrin of its original investors" sentence, I can understand "chagrin of its original investors". but I confused when I try to understand "much to"

The full sentence is:

> Millions of dollars over budget and months late, the planned software was finally ready for release, much to the chagrin of its original investors; although it actually had all of the capabilities that the original specification boasted of, the delay meant that it had already been surpassed by competitor's products.

(Source: [5 lb. Book of GRE Practice Problems](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=NpLlCgAAQBAJ&pg=PR90&lpg=PR90&dq=Millions+of+dollars+over+budget+and+months+late,+the+planned+software+was+finally+ready+for+release,&source=bl&ots=93um26ANBy&sig=oldo96TGofU3P3I5YDd6orl1Ppo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizl92c9vLZAhUIEJoKHcMXAxMQ6AEIETAC#v=onepage&q=Millions%20of%20dollars%20over%20budget%20and%20months%20late%2C%20the%20planned%20software%20was%20finally%20ready%20for%20release%2C&f=false))

Comment: For a good answer, see the comment on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/124698/164776) in ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pattern that can form adverbials, "To the X of Y"

> To the surprise of John, his wife announced she was pregnant.
>
> To the horror of everyone, a dead mouse was found in the bag of crisps.

This can be modified by "much" meaning "to a great extent", which can imply "not completely"

> Much to the chagrin of the orginial invetors, the software was millions of dollars over budget.

Means that "the software more expensive than expected and this annoyed most of the original investors."